# Symfony Security Authentication

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

Why in my Debug Panel I see "You are not authenticated." this I have [printscreen](http://sh.uploads.ru/8drP0.png) and this I want [printscreen](http://sh.uploads.ru/MBINY.png)
I use the [symfony_book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) and if I have home all works fine BUT:

**In my variant, user authenticate in ANOTHER SITE and my site I have user data for GET methods - EMAIL, SECRET KEY AND REFERENCE**

```
 http://aog.local/app_dev.php/auth/enko@gmail.com/962cc9a06924034d1285e8d75b2faf‌​2d/00223311121
```

How have this I can do authentication, how do I authenticate to appear global variable user [printscreen](http://sh.uploads.ru/MBINY.png) ????

I create auth service bit this service not authenticate

I use Symfony 2.6 and have entity Developer and User extends SUser ->  SUser implements UserInterface thgis is routing for auth:

```
#Enter routing
artel_profile_auth:
path:     /auth/{email}/{secretKey}/{referenceId}
defaults: { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:DeveloperProfile:auth }

login_route:
path:     /login
defaults: { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
path: /login_check
defaults: { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:Security:securityCheck }

index:
pattern:   /
defaults:  { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:Security:index }
```

and Action:

```
    public function authAction($email, $secretKey, $referenceId)
{
    $authenticator = $this->get('artel.profile.authenticator');
    try {
        $authDeveloper = $authenticator->auth($email, $secretKey, $referenceId);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('artel_profile_homepage', array('username' => $authDeveloper->getUsername())) .'#personal-information');
    } catch (\Exception $error) {

        return new Response($error->getCode() . ': '.$error->getMessage());
    }
}
```

and artel.profile.authenticator:

```
<?php
 namespace Artel\ProfileBundle\Helper;

 class Authenticator
{
const SESSION_NAME = 'developer_auth';

private $session;
private $secretAppKey;
private $developerRepository;
private $codeuserreferenceRepository;

public function __construct($session, $secretAppKey, $developerRepository, $codeuserreferenceRepository)
{
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->secretAppKey = $secretAppKey;
    $this->developerRepository = $developerRepository;
    $this->codeuserreferenceRepository = $codeuserreferenceRepository;
}

public function auth($email, $secretKey, $referenceId)
{
    $this->validateSecretAppKey($secretKey, $referenceId);
//todo: We need to match $referenceId with email in validateDeveloper
    $developer = $this->validateDeveloper($referenceId);
    $this->setSession($developer);

    return $developer;
}

public function authAdmin($email, $secretKey, $referenceId)
{
    $this->validateSecretAppKey($secretKey, $referenceId);
    //todo: We need to match $referenceId with email in validateDeveloper
    $developer = $this->validateAdminDeveloper($referenceId);
    $this->setSession($developer);

    return $developer;
}

public function check($developer)
{
    $result = false;

    $session = $this->session->get(self::SESSION_NAME);
    if ($session && $session == $developer->getId()) {
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->remove(self::SESSION_NAME);
}

protected function validateDeveloper($referenceId)
{
    $code_user_reference = $this->codeuserreferenceRepository->findOneByCodereference($referenceId);
    $id = $code_user_reference->getDeveloper()->getId();

    $developer = $this->developerRepository->findOneById($id);


    if (! $developer) {
        $this->exception('developer not found', 100);
    }

    return $developer;
}

protected function validateAdminDeveloper($referenceId)
{
    $code_user_reference = $this->codeuserreferenceRepository->findOneByCodereference($referenceId);

    $id = $code_user_reference->getDeveloper()->getId();

    $developer = $this->developerRepository->findOneById($id);
    $role = $developer->getRole();


    if ($role != 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        $this->exception('developer not Admin', 100);
    }

    return $developer;
}

protected function validateSecretAppKey($secretKey, $referenceId)
{
    if ($secretKey != md5($referenceId.$this->secretAppKey)) {
        $this->exception('secret ket is not valid', 101);
    }
}

protected function setSession($developer)
{
    $this->session->set(self::SESSION_NAME, $developer->getId());
}

protected function exception($message, $code)
{
    throw new \Exception($message, $code);
}
}
```

But in debug panel: "You are not authenticated. "
This is my secyrity, maybe the problem?|

```
security:
 encoders:
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developers:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CLIENT:   ROLE_USER
    ROLE_COMPANY:  ROLE_USER
    ROLE_FREELANCER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:    [ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_COMPANY, ROLE_FREELANCER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_db, user_dev, in_memory]
            providers: [user_dev, in_memory]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users, property: email }
    user_dev:
        entity: { class: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer, property: email }
    in_memory:
       memory:
         users:
            admin_tyty: { password: adminpass_tyty, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }


firewalls:
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**In my variant, user authenticate in ANOTHER SITE and my site I have user data for GET methods - EMAIL, SECRET KEY AND REFERENCE**

```
 http://aog.local/app_dev.php/auth/enko@gmail.com/962cc9a06924034d1285e8d75b2faf‌​2d/00223311121
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement authentication via your own login form, so users can actually authenticate: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

If your form has the proper routes, Symfony will handle the rest.

Comment: In my variant, user authenticate in ANOTHER SITE and my site I have user data for GET methods, 
`http://aog.local/app_dev.php/auth/enko@gmail.com/962cc9a06924034d1285e8d75b2faf2d/00223311121`
I create auth service bit this service not authenticate

Comment: Like cookbook and home page in my project work. But I have GET url from another site. I update my question

Comment: If you have a stateless app then you will not be able to authenticate your user there, so you should find a way like oAuth to do some authentication to archieve the second print-screen you've posted in your question.