# Symfony, twig transmit data

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

In symfony I have twig and I want to transmit data for action but in url for action I dont want see 'role', only transmit for action, how do this?
routing:

```
artel_admin_index:
path:     /{ida}/edit/{id}/submit
defaults: { _controller: ArtelProfileBundle:Dashboard:edit }
requirements: { _method: POST|GET }
```

twig:

```
<td>
<a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'ida': user.id, 'id': developer.id, 'role': user.role }) }}"> {{ developer.firstname }} {{ developer.lastname }}</a>
</td>
```

action:

```
    public function editAction($ida, $id)
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $value = $request->getSession()->get('role');
    dump($request, $value);exit;
```

And I see:

```
DashboardController.php on line 138:
Request {#7 ▼
+attributes: ParameterBag {#10 ▶}
+request: ParameterBag {#8 ▶}
+query: ParameterBag {#9 ▶}
+server: ServerBag {#13 ▶}
+files: FileBag {#12 ▶}
+cookies: ParameterBag {#11 ▶}
+headers: HeaderBag {#14 ▶}
#content: null
#languages: null
#charsets: null
#encodings: null
#acceptableContentTypes: null
#pathInfo: "/39/edit/116/submit"
#requestUri: "/app_dev.php/39/edit/116/submit"
#baseUrl: "/app_dev.php"
#basePath: null
#method: "GET"
#format: null
#session: Session {#151 ▶}
#locale: null
#defaultLocale: "en"
}

DashboardController.php on line 138:
"ROLE_COMPANY"
```

I try transmit $role indexAction -> editAction in indexAction I set:

```
public function indexAction($username)
{
    $user_role = $user->getRoles();
    $request->getSession()->set('role', $user_role[0]);
```

and in form I have action hoe in this action transmit this $role but this role not add in routing:

```
<td>
  <a href="{{ path('artel_admin_index', {'ida': user.id, 'id': developer.id}) }}"> {{ developer.firstname }} {{ developer.lastname }}</a>
</td>
```

in indexAction

```
    $user_role = $user->getRoles();
    $request->getSession()->set('role', $user_role[0]);
    $role = $request->getSession()->get('role');
    dump($user_role, $role);exit;
```

And I see

```
UserProfileController.php on line 69:
array:1 [▼
 0 => "ROLE_COMPANY"
]

UserProfileController.php on line 69:
"ROLE_COMPANY"
```

Now in index action I render in template ? Because now in indexAction I render some data and in template I have

Comment: you cant use GET, use POST. GET will always give you a query string. Create a mini form and use that instead.

Comment: Why do you want to submit `role` via the form? You can always get the roles from the authenticated user in the controller via `$this->getUser()->getRoles()`.

Comment: noy, now I have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670937/symfony-security-authentication

Comment: $this->getUser() = null

Comment: Then you should authenticate the user first. Passing the roles via a form looks like a security flaw to me. After that you can easily get the roles in every request.

Comment: I know, but how authenticate the user ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670937/symfony-security-authentication
In my variant, user authenticate in another site and my site I have user data for GET methods, I create auth service bit this service not authenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable from a view to the receiving controller you should use `POST` method.

You can achieve this, for example, submitting a form.

If you knew this data when executing the previous `action`, then you can store this information in session:

```
$request->getSession()->set('VARIABLE_NAME', $value);
```

And then get it back with:

```
$value = $request->getSession()->get('VARIABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: As you know   `$role` in `indexAction`, I would put it in session following my example

Comment: `set` does not return the value. If you want to check the setted value, you must use `get`

Comment: this wotk but where transfer requset, I update question

Comment: in my editAction I have request parameters [] I update question

Comment: Excuse-me, but I'm lost... You're executing `indexAction` to render a first template. There, you put `role` into session. Then, you don't need to pass `role` to your twig. Simply get it on `editAction` through the  `session`

Comment: I'm glad to have been useful!